# Should we have a large data volume (ldv) tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

A tough area of the platform is dealing with orgs with a LOT of data and the various limits that start to affect how you architect your solutions.  Salesforce has their own Large Data Volume group, should we have a tag for questions related to it?

Comment: Seems logical to me, speaking from the point of view of an Org with 450k+ Leads, 2.5m+ Tasks, etc.  :-P  I'm sure we're a drop in the bucket compared to some others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Makes sense to me, but I would spell out the label (`large-data-volume`) because for many users (me included), `ldv` doesn't really mean anything.